What is nvidia-dkms and why MIGHT I be seeing a crash report happen?
I have been using ubuntu 22.04 for a few years. I have installed nvidia drivers on my system, but that was over a year ago, and for the first time I see an error message pop up while I'm browsing the internet that says system program problem detected.
I proceeded to open the crash report and then went to send it hoping it would open a copy-able format to share. It lead me to a log in possibly for here, I wasn't paying attention much to be honest. So I didn't proceed with that.
I'm not very familiar with using the terminal to open anything, but I can see the crash report in var/crash. There are 3 items there all related to nvidia crash and all of them were generated on the same date and time (today when the error message appeared) and they are the only items in the folder.
I am not eager to use apport or to try to solve a problem that doesn't exist. There doesn't seem to be a problem with nvidia drivers, just this report being generated when I have not made any recent changes to anything with automatic updates turned off. Any suggestions about what you think I should do are appreciated. Thanks for your time.

nvidia-dkms is the NVIDIA driver components.  If you get regular crash reports about that then you might want to check the syslogs and see what errors are in the logs about nvidia.  Crash files are not easily human-readable.
